# How to horizontally stretch elements when using flex-box

Tags: css, web, flexbox

I am trying to strech inner objects horizontally so they will fill the width of their container.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The align-items Property</h1>

<p>The "align-items: stretch;" stretches the flex items to fill the container (this is default):</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The height of the inner div elements stretched thanks to the property:

```
align-items: stretch;
```

How to stretch **the width** of these elements too?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add `flex:1` to flex items:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>The align-items Property</h1>

<p>The "align-items: stretch;" stretches the flex items to fill the container (this is default):</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>
```

This guide could be very helpful for you: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

You are using flexbox with the default `flex-direction: row`. Which places the elements in a row and ajusts their width based on their initial width and flex properties.

This means that `align-items: stretch;` will stretch the items in such manner so they  so they fit the parent element but not in width, but in height. since their width is defined by the flex property;

use `flex: 1 1 auto;` to make the element fit it's parent.

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more details.

Comment: I don't want "this item should stretch horizontaly" to be a property of a flex item. Instead, I want "this row flexbox should stretch its items horizontally unless overriden per item" to be a property of the flexbox as a whole. How to?